# Accordion - display only one event at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like only one event to display at a time. When another event is clicked, it should hide the last event. Right now, all events are staying visible and I can't figure out how to hide previously clicked events.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I can hide all but one event at a time?

I would like only one event to display at a time. When another event is clicked, it should hide the last event. Right now, all events are staying visible and I can't figure out how to hide previously clicked events.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I can hide all but one event at a time?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FV Runners</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
.panel{
display:none;
color: orange;
}

#a:hover {
    color: gray;
}

.accordion + .panel:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="main"></div>

  <div id="pics">
    <div class="race_box">
  <img src="images/run1.jpg" id="5kpic" /><br />

  <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

  <div class="races" id="5k">
    <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">Mini Sprint</li>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>10/30/17, Memorial Park, Appleton</p>
        </div>
        <br>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">Iron Horse</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>11/6/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <br>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">Twilight Trail</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>11/13/17, River's Edge Park, Wrightstown</p>
        </div>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="race_box">
  <img src="images/run2.jpg" id="halfpic" /></button><br />
  <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

  <div class="races" id="half">
    <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
    <ul>

      <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox River Marathon</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>10/15/17, Pierce Park, Appleton</p>
        </div>
        <br>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">N.E.W. Half Marathon</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>10/29/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <br>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">Winnebago Run</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>11/27/17, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
        </div>

    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="race_box">
  <img src="images/run3.jpg" id="fullpic" /><br />
  <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

  <div class="races" id="full">
    <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
    <ul>

      <li class="accordion" id="a">Cheesehead Marathon</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>9/24/17, Pamperin Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <br>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">Chain O'Lakes Marathon</li>
      <div class="panel">
            <p>10/29/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <br>
      <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox Cities Marathon</li>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>11/12/17, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
        </div>


    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <script>


  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
 acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");


    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "none") {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        panel.style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to use the Jquery accordion component for this?

Comment: Yes I am. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @AllisonGandara can you tell which element you want hide?

Comment: When I click on the class=accordion I want the corresponding class=panel to show. But only the one it corresponds with and then when the next is clicked, the previous one should hide.

Comment: means when you click on _5k/10 Events_ then list should be visible of this event and hide list of other events, right?

Comment: For example, when I click on Mini Sprint... 10/30/17, Memorial Park, Appleton should display. Then when I click on Iron Horse... 11/6/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay should display, but the previous (10/30/17, Memorial Park, Appleton) should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, what I have done is when someone click on any event I hide every event except that event on which user has click and decide whether hide or show that event in main function.

```js
onload=hide;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        hide(this);
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
}
function hide(e){
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        if(e!==acc[i] && acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.value.indexOf("hide")<0)
          acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
}
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>FV Runners</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .panel {
            color: orange;
        }
        
        #a:hover {
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="main"></div>

    <div id="pics">
        <div class="race_box">

            <div class="races" id="5k">
                <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Mini Sprint</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>10/30/17, Memorial Park, Appleton</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Iron Horse</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>11/6/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Twilight Trail</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>11/13/17, River's Edge Park, Wrightstown</p>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="race_box">

            <div class="races" id="half">
                <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
                <ul>

                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox River Marathon</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>10/15/17, Pierce Park, Appleton</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">N.E.W. Half Marathon</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>10/29/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Winnebago Run</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>11/27/17, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="race_box">

            <div class="races" id="full">
                <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
                <ul>

                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Cheesehead Marathon</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>9/24/17, Pamperin Park, Green Bay</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Chain O'Lakes Marathon</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>10/29/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox Cities Marathon</li>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>11/12/17, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to show only one event at a time is to give all events a class you can use to hide them all.

So when you want to show a new event, you just

1. Select for your class and hide everything
2. Show the specific event

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were intent on using Jquery's [accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) component, here's an adaptation from their example page. Also here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rj1dwtdh/17/).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".accordion").accordion({
          header: 'h3',
          collapsible: true,
          expanded: false,
          active: false,
          autoHeight: false,
          autoActivate: false
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="main">
      <h3>5k/10k Events</h3>
      <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Mini Sprint</h3>
        <div class='panel'>
          <p>10/30/17, Memorial Park, Appleton</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Iron Horse</h3>
        <div class='panel'>
          <p>11/6/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Twilight Trail</h3>
        <div class='panel'>
          <p>11/13/17, River's Edge Park, Wrightstown</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
      <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Fox River Marathon</h3>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>10/15/17, Pierce Park, Appleton</p>
        </div>
        <h3>N.E.W. Half Marathon</h3>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>10/29/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <h3>
          Winnebago Run</h3>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>11/27/17, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
      <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Cheesehead Marathon</h3>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>9/24/17, Pamperin Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Chain O'Lakes Marathon</h3>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>10/29/17, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Fox Cities Marathon</h3>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>11/12/17, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Obviously, styling is still left up to you.

Hope this helps!